# how to get a post of twitter in my asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using this code for getting a **post** of **twitter** in my asp.net mvc project. it's give proper output.
but problem is that i want to get custom display. **i want get only user name and post that add into my design code.**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/jay_patel" data-widget-id="########">Tweets by @jay /a>

<script>
    !function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id; js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: what are the things that you dont want ?

Comment: I don't want this design. i want get only user name and post text.